# show list as table in xsl-fo

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I'm trying to render this list as a table in xsl-fo

```
<ul class="tablelist">
             <li class="a">A</li>
             <li class="a">A
    </li>
             <li class="b">B
    </li>
             <li class="b">B
    </li>
             <li class="a">A</li>
             <li class="b">B</li>
             <li class="a">A</li>
             </ul>
```

All the ones with class A in the left column, all the ones with class B in the right column.

My current solution:

```
  <fo:table>
              <fo:table-column column-number="1" column-width="30mm"/>
        <fo:table-column column-number="2" />
  <fo:table-body>
      <xsl:for-each select="li[@class='a']">
        <fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-cell column-number="1">
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
      </xsl:for-each>
              <xsl:for-each select="li[@class='b']">
        <fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-cell column-number="2">
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
      </xsl:for-each>
      </fo:table-body>
  </fo:table>
```

... doesnt work, of course. What would I need to change?

Thanks for help!

EDIT:

Desired output in this case would be:

```
<fo:table>
<fo:table-body>
<fo:table-row>
<fo:table-cell>
<fo:block>
A
</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell>
<fo:block>
B
</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
<fo:table-row>
<fo:table-cell>
<fo:block>
A
</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell>
<fo:block>
B
</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
<fo:table-row>
<fo:table-cell>
<fo:block>
A
</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell>
<fo:block>
B
</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
<fo:table-row>
<fo:table-cell>
<fo:block>
A
</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell>
<fo:block/
</fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
</fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
```

because there are four class="a" and three class="b"elements. So, 4 rows in total, in 4 rows the left cell is A and in three of those rows, the right column is B.

Hope, it is a bit clearer now!

Comment: If you change `permitted` to `a` and `prohibited` to `b`, you get a table with 4 rows with `A` in the left column (nothing in the right) and then 3 rows with `B` in the right column (nothing in the left). Is that what you want? You should add an example of your desired XSL-FO output.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It change the code and provided an example of the desired output.

Comment: What should happen if there are more `b` elements than `a` elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `position()` to apply-templates to the element with the opposite class that's in the same position.

If you know that there will always be more `a` class elements than `b` class elements (or if you don't care what happens to the remaining `b` class elements), you could do something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="ul[@class='tablelist']">
    <fo:table>
        <fo:table-column column-number="1" column-width="30mm"/>
        <fo:table-column column-number="2" />
        <fo:table-body>
            <xsl:for-each select="li[@class='a']">
                <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell column-number="1">
                        <fo:block>
                            <xsl:apply-templates/>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell column-number="2">
                        <fo:block>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="../li[@class='b'][position()=$pos]"/>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </fo:table-body>
    </fo:table>
</xsl:template>
```

If you do care about those `b` class elements, when there are more `b` than `a`, you could do something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="ul[@class='tablelist']">
    <fo:table>
        <fo:table-column column-number="1" column-width="30mm"/>
        <fo:table-column column-number="2" />
        <fo:table-body>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="count(li[@class='a']) >= count(li[@class='a'])">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="li[@class='a']" mode="createRow"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="li[@class='b']" mode="createRow"/>                        
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </fo:table-body>
    </fo:table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="li[@class='a']" mode="createRow">
    <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
    <fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-cell column-number="1">
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell column-number="2">
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="../li[@class='b'][position()=$pos]"/>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="li[@class='b']" mode="createRow">
    <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
    <fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-cell column-number="1">
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="../li[@class='a'][position()=$pos]"/>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell column-number="2">
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Your second solution was the one for me. Although I had to change your apply-templates in the li-templates to xsl:value-of because of my other xml markup. But this is exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way you could look at it:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <table>
        <xsl:call-template name="generate-rows">
            <xsl:with-param name="left" select="ul/li[@class='a']"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="right" select="ul/li[@class='b']"/>
        </xsl:call-template>    
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="generate-rows">
    <xsl:param name="left"/>
    <xsl:param name="right"/>
    <xsl:param name="i" select="1"/>
    <xsl:if test="$i &lt;= count($left) or $i &lt;= count($right)">
        <row>
            <cell><xsl:value-of select="$left[$i]"/></cell>
            <cell><xsl:value-of select="$right[$i]"/></cell>
        </row>
        <xsl:call-template name="generate-rows">
            <xsl:with-param name="left" select="$left"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="right" select="$right"/>      
            <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i + 1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Nice answer (+1). Not sure why I didn't think of that; I've used the same technique in the past.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your reply, as well. I accepted Daniel's answer because I got some errors with the parameters when I used yours. But that is probably because of the way I structured my stylesheets. I don't have time to look at it in detail just now, but your solution is probably working fine, too.